# If an answer already exist outside Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

If I have a question and I was planning to put it on Stack Overflow, but I found the answer shortly later outside, should I put that question any way in the site to enrich it (with answer or without answer)?

Comment: Servy's answer in that proposed duplicate contains the most important information (imho): *"If you want to self answer a question both the question and the answer both need to be quality posts that meet all of the site's standards."*

Comment: @Stijn what if the question and the answer indeed meets the quality standards of the site?, do you think if will be appropriate to put that specific and detailed question for others to benefit from?

Comment: Yes, then by all means feel free to post your Q&A :)